# Transforming an HTML form to PHP to PDF

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf

I want to be able to print the PDF file as it is shown in a PHP site. I am using FPDF to generate the pdf file.

Here is what I want:

1. **HTML**: I have made a form where you can add more text fields using JavaScript, and therefore the “name” in the form is written as: `name="inputnumber[]"`. (not sure if the `[]` makes any difference) example (it is not the actual code, just an example):

   ```
   <form method="post" action="fpdf_test.php">
       <input type="text" name="inpustnumber[]" value="" size="30">
       <input type="text" name="inpustnumber2[]" value="" size="30">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   ```
2. **PHP**: I build a table where I can multiply and echo/display the different form inputs and results in a . For example: *fpdf_test.php*

   ```
   <?php 
   echo “<table><tr><td>”;
   echo $_POST[‘inputnumber’];
   echo “</td><td>”;
   echo $_POST[‘inputnumber2’];
   echo “</td></tr><tr><td>”;

   $result = $_POST[‘inputnumber’] * $_POST[‘inputnumber’]; 
   echo $result;
   echo “</td></tr></table>”;
   ?>
   ```
3. **FPDF**: Here’s where I must give up; I feel like I have tried every possible solution and combination, and looked everywhere on the net.

Is it possible to generate a PDF file, that includes the `<table>` and PHP array results?

Comment: You know you don't have to use so many `echo`s. Just a comment.

Comment: I know, it was just to make it more reable.

- Guess there is no way of doing this, been looking for a solution for days. You can't turn a PHP array into a PDF...